# Can a Turkish e-Visa allow me entry to Northern Cyprus?

Tags: visas, turkey, nigerian-citizens, northern-cyprus

I have been to Turkey in 2017, but presently have a USA visa and a Turkey visa on a Nigerian Passport.

Can a Turkish e-visa allow me entry to Northern Cyprus?

Answer (score 6):

[Apparently not](http://mfa.gov.ct.tr/consular-info/visa-regulations/):

> NOTE: The nationals of the Syrian Arab Republic, the Federal Republic of Nigeria and the Republic
> of Armenia are under obligation to apply in person to a TRNC
> Representative Office abroad to obtain a visa prior to traveling.

Comment: What an odd set of exceptional countries!